# git: how to merge a pull request into a fork?

Tags: git, github

My situation is as follows:
- I have a fork of an opensource github project.
- I do all of my development in my forked repo in branches from the develop branch
- There is an unmerged pull request I need in the main repo's develop branch
- To test the unmerged pull request I created a new directory and cloned origin to it then fetched the unmerged request to the main
- Now that I've tested the unmerged pull request, i need to merge the pull request with my fork of develop.

What steps will allow me to merge the pull request into my local fork?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
~/your-repo $ git remote add pr-source https://github.com/<user-providing-pull-request>/<repo-name>

~/your-repo $ git fetch pr-source

~/your-repo $ git merge pr-source/<pull-request-branch-name>
```

Note that:

- you don't need the main repo, either from github or cloned locally
- you don't need a clone of the repo providing the pull request, you just need it as a **remote**
- you don't have to call it `pr-source`, I was just using that as "pull request source"