# Merge Pull Request from Upstream Branch into a Forked Repository

Tags: git, github, merge, git-fork

I'm new to git, so forgive me for any mistakes I make with my terminology.

I have a forked repo. In the origin repo, someone makes a pull request containing a bunch of different commits. That pull request is then merged into the origin. I would also like that pull request, so I want it merged into my repo too. What's the correct way of doing this? I tried cherry-picking each commit, and that worked, but I feel like that isn't the right way to get things done.

Edit: I'll attempt to more specific about exact structure of what's happening and what I want to do.

There is the original repo we'll call A.

A group of developers forked that repo into a mostly separate project that we'll call B.

I forked B so that I could create my own branches and contribute with pull requests, this is repo C.

There's a change to repo A through a pull request. This PR was made after the fork that created B, and we want the commits from A's PR in repo B.

In order to add it to B, I need to do the same merge they did to A, and do it on my repo C, then make a pull request for B with the changes.

Right now, rather than merge the PR commits from A into C, I instead just cherry picked the commits from the PR and applied them in order. This worked, but I don't feel like this is the best way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check out the branch you wish to merge to on your fork. Usually, you
   will merge into master.

   `git checkout master`
2. Pull the desired branch from the upstream repository. This method
   will retain the commit history without modification.

   `git pull https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git BRANCH_NAME`
3. If there are conflicts, resolve them. For more information, see
   "Addressing merge conflicts".
4. Commit the merge.
5. Push the merge to your GitHub repository.

   `git push origin master`

Comment: When I try this, it pulls in a ton of files that are irrelevant to the pull request

Comment: Are you trying to merge your pull request's branch?

Comment: I added some more explanation to my post. I'm sorry if I'm not describing it clearly, it feels like a convoluted scenario.

Comment: This probably has a better answer for you (either for me): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628859/git-how-to-merge-a-pull-request-into-a-fork